# How to kill line of PID?

Tags: bash, command-line, process, kill, process-management

I have process which created multiple PID's. I want to kill all those PID's. I have tried
 `pkill <process_name>`.

But PID not getting killed as they were wait to resource releasing.

I have managed to get PID list with

```
ps -ef | grep <process_name> | awk '{print $2}'
```

which gives process ID list but how can I kill all those listed PIDs ?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the output of `pgrep -lf <process_name>` ? if it gives only the relevant processes, you can kill with `pkill -f <process_name>`

Comment: [You probably don't want to do this...](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_kill_a_process_by_name.3F__I_need_to_get_the_PID_out_of_ps_aux_.7C_grep_....)

Comment: @l0b0 Why? because some web page says so? The `pgrep -lf` verification covers everything that page warns about. You can see exactly what you are about to pkill.

Comment: @l0b0 how is `pgrep/pkill` different from `ps -ef | grep <prco name>`? Since it doesn't, you claim the authoritative answer is - since you didn't think to store the ppid in advance, you're out of luck. Don't trust ps names. They might lie.

Comment: Hold on, I didn't say to use `pgrep`/`pkill` instead of `ps | grep`; they're equally bad. If you read the linked web page it explains how to do it cleanly, by making sure that the *parent* process is responsible for killing/relaunching processes rather than relying on a PID file or `pgrep`/`pkill`. Of course, I assume OP is trying to automate this because of the form of the question. If that's not the case there's no point in being picky.

Comment: @l0b0 The major issue I have with the linked solution is the complete disregard for daemons, which are always detached from the parent to init (1). Assuming that all processes are always run from from terminal is somewhat naive.

Comment: @Dani_l Daemons like (AFAIK) MariaDB and Apache httpd use a top-level process to keep track of all their sub-processes, and therefore follow this pattern. By making the top-level process a simple wrapper you can provide a single interface to keep track of all the workers, and you won't need a PID file or `p*` commands. If you still think this is a bad idea I suggest asking on programmers.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pipe the output to `xargs` e.g.

```
ps -ef | grep <process_name> | awk '{print $2}' | xargs /bin/kill
```

But why doesn't your `pkill` command work?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
pgrep process_name | xargs kill
```

or

```
ps -e | awk '/[p]roces_name/ {system("kill "$1}
```

Comment: Or `pkill -f` ...